# How to go through a list of urls to retrieve page data - Python

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In a .py file, I have a variable that's storing a list of urls.  How do I properly build a loop to retrieve the code from each url, so that I can extract specific data items from each page?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

#Read csv
csvfile = open("gymsfinal.csv")
csvfilelist = csvfile.read()
print csvfilelist

#Get data from each url
def get_page_data():
    for page_data in csvfilelist.splitlines():
        r = requests.get(page_data.strip())
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        return soup

pages = get_page_data()
print pages
```

Comment: Added code I've currently got

Comment: You are not calling `get_page_data`. You are also looping over `csvfilelist` which is a string (so you are looping over each character), you can change that to `csvfilelist.splitlines()` to loop over each line.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Right now it's just extracting the code from the first url though.  What would I need to do to repeat that for all urls?

Comment: @McLeodx how many URLs have you got in the CSV file and are you interested in making it scale and behave in a non-blocking manner? Thanks.

Comment: There's 98 urls and not sure about the implications of scaling and non-blocking, but for the sake of this lets say scaling isn't important

Answer (score 1):

By not using the `csv` module, you are reading the `gymsfinal.csv` file as text files. Read through the documentation on reading/writing csv files here: [CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Also you will get only the first page's `soup` content from your current code. Because `get_page_data()` function will return after creating the first soup. For your current code, You can `yield` from the function like,

```
def get_page_data():
    for page_data in csvfilelist.splitlines():
        r = requests.get(page_data.strip())
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        yield soup

pages = get_page_data()

# iterate over the generator
for page in pages:
    print pages
```

Also close the file you just opened.